# Regex to split positive/negative float/int from string

Tags: python, regex

How can I adapt the following code to return the words and the numbers from this example?

The regex below extracts the positive and negative ints/floats well but I would like to keep the words ('abc') also.

```
numeric_const_pattern = '[-+]? (?: (?: \d* \. \d+ ) | (?: \d+ \.? ) )(?: [Ee] [+-]? \d+ ) ?'
rx = re.compile(numeric_const_pattern, re.VERBOSE)
rx.findall("-1 abc -1m abc -2.0 abc -2.0m abc 1 abc 1m abc 2.0 abc 2.0m abc")
```

Thanks

Iain

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep all the `abc` strings, and the only change you want to make to the numeric strings is to remove the `m`, it seems like it would be easier to reframe the problem as "remove `m` from the end of each word":

```
>>> [x[:-1] if x.endswith("m") else x
... for x in
... "-1 abc -1m abc -2.0 abc -2.0m abc 1 abc 1m abc 2.0 abc 2.0m abc".split()
... ]
['-1', 'abc', '-1', 'abc', '-2.0', 'abc', '-2.0', 'abc', '1', 'abc', '1', 'abc', '2.0', 'abc', '2.0', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex matches "any number (optional negative and floating point) OR 'abc'":

```
rx = re.compile(r'(-?\d+\.?\d*|abc)', re.VERBOSE)
rx.findall("-1 abc -1m abc -2.0 abc -2.0m abc 1 abc 1m abc 2.0 abc 2.0m abc")

['-1', 'abc', '-1', 'abc', '-2.0', 'abc', '-2.0', 'abc', '1', 'abc', '1', 'abc', '2.0', 'abc', '2.0', 'abc']
```

Note however that your existing regex has a lot more complicated test cases so either your regex is too complicated, or the question/sample dat too simple.